# Why is jQuery validation not working here

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a form with jquery validation but it does not show the expected error message. How can I set it so it show my messages?

here is the javascript that I am using:

```
$(function () {

$("#registerForm").validate({
    rules: {
        inputEmail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        inputEmail: "Please enter a valid email address"
    }
});
});
```

Please have a look at the jsfiddle link of my code:

[JSFIDDLE code with html/bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/f7jq6/6/) ***Updated**

On the live version of my site it does not even show the popup message that is appearing in jsfiddle. Please help me in fixing this.

Ideally I would like to display inline messages or a summary if validation fails but don't know how to do this. I was hoping if jquery validation works then I would be able to specify custom functions to handle `success` and `error` events.

I would appreciate if someone can help me out here. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

[image: Screen capture of fiddler response which I get]

Comment: Your problem is very unclear.  The code you posted above is working as proven by [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7jq6/6/).  It is showing your custom error message.

Comment: The error message that I am getting is `Please fill out this field` or `Please enter an email address` whereas the message that I expect is `Please enter a valid email address`. Are you getting a different result? Also, did you try the form in live link? Over there it is not even showing a message.

Comment: In [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7jq6/6/), I am seeing exactly what I expected and stated previously, the custom error message as defined in your code:  "Please enter a valid email address".

Comment: Strange, I wish I could get the same response as you are getting. I have just tried it in Chrome, Firefox and IE10 and all of them show `Please fill out this field` styled differently. I have also attached the screen shot of the recent attempt to run it. Can you tell if you can see any error messages on the `live` link as well?

Comment: maybe I am missing something when running fiddler. I assume all I have to do is click on submit button without an input? or is there something else that needs to be checked/enabled/clicked?

Comment: I simply clicked your submit button.  See:  http://oi44.tinypic.com/be7uqb.jpg

Comment: All I can tell you is that I am very familiar with the usage of the jQuery Validate plugin and, as per your code in the jsFiddle, the result I'm getting is exactly what I am expecting to get.

Comment: hmm so do you think it is a browser compatibility issue then?

Comment: I have no idea.  So far, it's working fine for me in Safari and Firefox.  Does your HTML pass HTML validation at http://validator.w3.org/ ?

Comment: This error (`Line 404, Column 106: Duplicate ID inputPassword`) would cause JavaScript issues, maybe not this issue, but certainly another:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fs472955393.websitehome.co.uk%2FSignUp&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: the only difference that I see in your image is that you are on a mac whereas I have tried this on Windows 7 (chrome and firefox) and Windows 8 (Firefox 21, IE10, Chrome 27.0.1453.116) so far and getting the same response as attached in my image. But surely it's not an OS issue?

Comment: JavaScript does not care about OS... and I've tried your fiddle on different machines as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32282/discussion-between-sttaq-and-sparky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how you still have this issue even after I've removed jQuery and jQuery Validate from the jsFiddle?

http://www.jsfiddle.net/xRRZb/4

The pop-up bubbles and over-riding messages are generated directly by the browser thanks to HTML5... nothing to do with any of your JavaScript or jQuery code.

So since you've already defined the `required` and `email` rules within `.validate()`, remove `required` and `type="email"` from your inline HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="E.g. youremail@website.com" />
```

**DEMO:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/xRRZb/6**

---

**EDIT:**

jQuery Validate 1.8 is quite old.  Consider upgrading to version 1.11.1

In fact, this is likely your whole problem.  [Version 1.11.1 dynamically adds a `novalidate="novalidate"` attribute to the `form` tag to disable HTML5 validation](http://jsfiddle.net/cEy9h/1/) when the plugin is being used.

Unfortunately, [version 1.8 does not have this feature](http://jsfiddle.net/cEy9h/).

Alternatively, you could manually add the `novalidate` attribute to ensure that you disable HTML5 validation.  However, if you manually add the `novalidate` attribute, there will be no fallback.

Comment: @sttaq, sorry... I mistyped my URLs... fixed.

Comment: Thanks for you help. The issue is fixed in jsfiddle but not on the live even though the html is valid. There it is not showing the error message and I think that it is not validating. I will try to use the newer version and see what happens. I still don't understand if html5 validation was there then why is it not showing up on the live?

Comment: I've found my mistake at last. argh need to give myself a beating for it. I was including jquery validate twice in my html and this was causing both html5 and jquery validation to fail arrgh. The reason I did not realize this is because my page is composed of partial views and in one of them I had forgotten to remove the scripts. Thanks a lot for helping me anyway :)